# Laravel 5.6 Image Intervention Library: 'Image Source Not Readable'

Tags: laravel, image, intervention

I'm using Image Intervention Library for image resizing, i've done the following steps:

**1- Install Library:** composer require intervention/image

**2- Usage in code:**

```
    $file            = $request->file('logo');
    $destinationPath = 'db_images/public/';
    $filename        = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $extension       = explode(".",$filename)[1];
    $name            = md5(microtime()).".".$extension;
    $image_path      = $destinationPath.$name;
```

> $img             = Image::make($filename)->resize(254,
>   179)->save($image_path);

```
    $file->move($destinationPath,$img);
```

**Issue Is:**
When i try to upload the file using the above code this will return me 'Image Source is not readable'.

Pleas help me in resolving this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are passing only the filename to the `make` method, you have to pass either the file object or the filepath:

file:

```
$img = Image::make($file)->resize(254, 179)->save($image_path);
```

path:

```
$img = Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(254, 179)->save($image_path);
```